# How do I delete the _prisma_migrations table?

Tags: prisma

I'm using prisma and deploying it to fly.io. I deleted the migrations in the prisma/migrations folder. When I run prisma migrate deploy it still applies the migrations that I deleted. How do I delete the _prisma_migrations table in order to completely get rid of the deleted migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sqlite3 terminal.
Open the terminal by using the command `sqlite3`
Then use the  `DROP TABLE _prisma_migrations;` command

Comment: And did it work out as expected?